# Sending HTML or JSON response depending on the client

Tags: php, rest, laravel, laravel-5

I have a Laravel application with Eloquent entities and their respective [RESTful resource controllers](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/controllers#restful-resource-controllers), like the following:

#### The model

```
class Entity extends Eloquent {
    ...
}
```

#### The controller

```
class EntityContoller {

    public function index() {
        Entity $entities = Entity::all();
        return view('entity.index', compact($entities));
    }

    ... // And many more routes like that
}
```

Now I am building an android application, and instead of returning views, I need the data as JSON.

In my current solution, for every request I make from my Android application, I add a get query parameter `contentType=JSON`. I detect that in the controller, and send the data accordingly like the following. But this seems tedious, and I have to write the same condition everywhere.

```
class EntityContoller {

    public function index() {
        Entity $entities = Entity::all();

        if(Request::get('contentType', 'JSON')) return $entities;
        return view('entity.index', compact($entities));
    }

    ... // And many more routes like that
}
```

**What is the best way I can do this, without having to write this condition in every controller action?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't want to change your controllers, then you could use a [middleware](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/middleware#defining-middleware) that alters the response **after** it is returned from the controller.

The middleware would receive the response from the controller, check for `contentType == JSON` and then return the proper response.

The middleware would look like this:

```php
use Closure;
class JsonMiddleware {
    public function handle($request, Closure $next) {
        // Get the response from the controller
        $response = $next($request);

        // Return JSON if necessary
        if ($request->input('contentType') == 'JSON') {
            // If you want to return some specific JSON response
            // when there are errors, do that here.

            // If response is a view, extract the data and return it as JSON
            if (is_a($response, \Illuminate\View\View::class)) {
                return response()->json($response->getData());
            }
        }

        return $response;
    }
}
```

You would then register the middleware in `app/Http/Kernel.php` by appending it to the `$routeMiddleware` array.

```php
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    // New Middleware
    'json' => \App\Http\Middleware\JsonMiddleware::class,
];
```

Then you would just assign the middleware to routes that might return JSON.

```php
Route::get('user/{user_id}', ['middleware' => 'json', 'uses' => 'App\UserController@getUser']);
```

You can read more about middleware [here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/middleware#defining-middleware) and registering and assigning middleware [here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/middleware#registering-middleware).

You can read about sending JSON responses in Laravel [here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/responses#other-responses).

Comment: This seems like a nice solution. I like the fact that I can add the `json` middleware to specific functions in the controller, or all of them. Or I can even easily add more types responses, for instance, different views for mobile and desktop displays.

Answer (score 2):

How about a custom response class? Let me give you an idea. Create a new class or service:

```
class ResourceResponse{

    public function __construct($request, $object, $view = null){
        // setting values
    }

    public function __toString(){
        if ($this->request->get('contentType') == 'JSON'){
            return $this->object;
        }

        // view as fallback
        return view($this->view, compact($this->object));
    }
}
```

Then in your resources just call the function like using the view name as a fallback if json type is not specified:

```
public function index(Request $request) {
    $entities = Entity::all();
    return new ResourceResponse($request, $entities, 'entity.index'); 
}
```

If you are pretty sure that the response should be JSON format, then you can forget the view name:

```
public function index(Request $request) {
    $entities = Entity::all();
    return new ResourceResponse($request, $entities); 
}
```

> `$request` parameter at `index()` method make use of type-hint as described at [Laravel 5's docs](http://laravel.com/docs/master/requests#accessing-the-request)

Answer (score 1):

First create BaseController with protected function createView

```
class BaseController extends Controller
{
    protected function createView($object)
    {
        if (Request::get('contentType', 'JSON')) return $object;
        return view('entity.index', compact($object));
    }
}
```

Then in every controller extends this Base Controller

```
class EntityController extends BaseController
{
    public function index()
    {
        $entities = Entity::all()
        return $this->createView($entites);
    }

    public function get($id)
    {
        $entity = Entity::find($id);
        return $this->createView($entity);
    }
}
```

If there any others exception like multiple object or error, there is no other way to handle it individually.

Comment: I'd have to create this function in every controller I have. Also, some functions may return multiple objects, or they may redirect to a different route, or throw and error, or throw back old inputs (in case some validation exists on the request).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer of BrokenBinary: In Laravel 8 `$response` is never an instance of `Illuminate\View\View`. But you can get it if you call `getOriginalContent()` on `$response`.

```
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;
use Illuminate\View\View;

class JsonMiddleware {
    public function handle(
        Request $request,
        Closure $next
    ) {
        // Get the response from the controller
        $response = $next( $request );

        // Return JSON if necessary
        if ( $request->expectsJson() ) {
            // If you want to return some specific JSON response
            // when there are errors, do that here.

            // If response is a view, extract the data and return it as JSON
            if ( $this->isView( $response ) ) {
                $originalContent = $response->getOriginalContent();

                return response()->json(
                    $originalContent->getData()
                );
            }
        }

        return $response;
    }

    private function isView( Response $response ) {
        return (
            $response->getOriginalContent() instanceof View
        );
    }
}
```