# laravel 5 return HTML or JSON depending on route

Tags: php, laravel, view, routes, laravel-5

I want to show different output - JSON or HTML.

I cannot use the `\Request::ajax()` feature as I just get normal request (JSON response is not based on XHR-Requests).

Is there perhaps a possibility to distinguish the output by different routes? E.g. check if the controller is called by a route with the prefix "mob" and then create a switch for the output based on that?

**app/Http/routes.php:**

```php
Route::group( ['prefix' => 'api'], function(  ) {

  Route::resource( 'activation', 'ActivationController' ); 
  //...
} 

Route::group( ['prefix' => 'mob'], function(  ) {

  Route::resource( 'activation', 'ActivationController' ); 
  //...
}
```

**app/Http/Controllers/ActivationController:**

```php
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Activation;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
class ActivationController extends Controller {

public function index()
{
    $activation = Activation::all(  );

    // switch to decide which output to show, based on the routes...
    if ($prefix == "mob") {
      return response()->view('template', compact($activation)); // not sure if it works this way
    } else {          
      return response()->json($activation);
    }

}

//...
```

I am open for pragmatic and easy solutions. Must not be the routes-solution, but a way where I do not have to change much code.

Comment: You could use the accepted answer on this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32383038/sending-html-or-json-response-depending-on-the-client/32385528#32385528). Just edit the middleware so it doesn't check for `contentType` in the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Request::is() method that accepts wildcards/placeholders.
So you can do something like:

```
if($request->is('mob/*')) {
    // do your mob response
} else {
    // do the other response
}
```

If you have this everytime you do a response than you can write a custom response macro that handles the if and just take the data as an array and return this as json or give this to your blade view.

Comment: This looks interessting, have to try it. The custom response was my next intention after the switch.

Comment: I get an error `Undefined variable: request`. How do I access it correctly?

Comment: `if ( \Request::is( 'mob/*' ) ) { }` did the trick. Do I need to specify something special to use `$request->is()`?

Comment: In the controller method you can define, as first parameter, the $request as follows: method(Request $request, $theOtherOnes) { ... }

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the prefix as a parameter, then handle your business in the action based on given prefix

REF: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#route-group-prefixes